# Are there any reasons not to set `html,body { height:100% }`?

Tags: css

*Is `min-height` more appropriate?*

Or for that matter, is it even appropriate for me to be setting all of my fullscreen backgrounds to both `html` and  `body`? Can this be set to `html` alone?

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(blah.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  }
```

Comment: You just have to control your scrollable content in another container

Comment: only `body` html name and is not very convenient but if used

Comment: @Chad: I'm not certain if it's what you meant, but you've stirred a lot of thought in me. I suppose `html,body{height:100%; overflow:scroll||auto;}` could cause the `<html>` or `<body>` to perform internal scrolling, rather than full viewport scrolling.. Perhaps causing `$window.scrollTop()` to give unexpected results? I think this only presents a problem when `overflow` is set to anything other than the default of `visible`..

Comment: Of course window.scrollTop would not give the information you wanted if you changed the scrollable element. That's not to say you couldn't just as easily do like `$('#container').scrollTop()`

Comment: @Chad: So, then, this means `html,body{height:100%;}` will not affect the viewport's scrolling behavior, yeah?

Comment: Here's a small example of what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/vnLs2/ The inner element has the scrollable content. I actually use this technique a lot to simulate consistent fixed position on all mobile browsers.

Comment: @Chad: Does [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/HvKLC/) of your fiddle have undesirable affects for some mobile browsers?

Comment: if you set html and body to height to 100%, you need the purpose to do so , like retrieving height of window so you can apply a min-height to your main wrapper or say that my four divs direct child of body should be 25% each of window's height. set margin to 0 for body to avoid scrolling bar even if body is empty

Comment: @GCyrillus: Good thing to point out! `*{margin:0;padding:0}` should be set to prevent an empty body from producing scrollbars [(Updated fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/HvKLC/1/) Anyways, isn't my need for the background image to fill the viewport reason enough?

Answer (score 0):

everything is drawn on `body`, html is the main document, if you can give styles but is not highly recommended because `body` and `html` in question are the same.

`min-height` is used whenever a screen this size that does not want.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-image: url(blah.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  }
```

Comment: This is a CSS snippet, not an answer.